# How to sort this ArrayList by various parameters in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have the following collection in my driver class:

```
ArrayList<SoftDrink> drinks = new ArrayList<>();
```

where `SoftDrink` has three private instance variable (there are accessor methods in the class):

`String name;`
`String colour;`
`int volume;`

Users are asked to input information about a drink and SoftDrink objects are added to the ArrayList like this:

`drinks.add(new SoftDrink(drinkName, colour, volume));`

When the user is done adding drinks I want the program to print out a list of the soft drinks that the user has entered, sorted first by alphabetical order of name, then by alphabetical order of colour, then by volume (in ascending order).

Example:

`Coke Red 500`
`Coke Silver 500`
`Fanta Orange 300`
`Fanta Orange 500`

What is the most Javaish way I could go about comparing these objects in the ArrayList and then sorting them approriately according to these various parameters?

Comment: write a comparator and do it

Comment: With Java8 this article might help: http://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/31/java-8-friday-goodies-lambdas-and-sorting/ to write an easy to maintain solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
List<SoftDrink>  drinks= new ArrayList<SoftDrink>();

SoftDrink drink;
for(int i=0;i<numberOfDrinks;i++) {
  drink = new SoftDrink();
  drink.setname(...);
  drinks.add(drink);
}

//Sorting
Collections.sort(drinks, new Comparator<SoftDrink>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(SoftDrink  drink1, SoftDrink  drink2) {
            return  drink1.drinkName.compareTo(drink2.drinkName);
        }
    });
```

Comment: it only compares drinkname

Comment: Not gonna do all the work for him ;)